# Error executing command, exiting

Tags: command-line, nodejs, mongodb

I'm trying to install node.js 12 on Ubuntu 18 and following the instructions, when I type

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

I got the next text:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                     
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.0 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_18.10  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4ABE1AC7557BEFF9
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_18.10  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

I guess this is the reason why every time that I run

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I got the version 8 instead of 10.
Anyone knows why is this happening? How I got to this point?
And if the security of my system is at risk, how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be having obsolete source PPAs. Remove every other apt sources:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try again.